# Can you use nebula.gl without a Map and React?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking to use nebula.gl (https://nebula.gl/) to add drawing and editing tools to a three.js app (which does not have anything to do with geographic maps). I want to draw and edit just in pixel coordinates (not geographic coordinates). Is this possible? I can't see an example of how to do this but it feels like it should be possible.

I'm looking for a snippet showing how to add the nebula.gl drawing tools to a canvas that doesn't use a map and doesn't use react.